# Custom shape in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, paintcomponent

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D) g;      
    MyShape c = new MyShape();
    ga.draw(c);
}
```

I want that `MyShape` class to contain the info required to draw a circle with a number inside it.

So, I guess I need to create some kind of container/component, and drew what I need (the circle and the number) inside it, and then pass it further to the method I've pasted above.

The problem is I don't know what class to extend ... and the rest of the story.

Comment: Extend `Object`.  As to the 'rest of the story', I have no idea, perhaps that will become more clear when you ask a specific question.  ..Or *any* question, for that matter.

Comment: I didn't extended or implemented anything after all. I've just passed the Graphics object from my main class into the object itself.

Comment: *"I didn't extended .. anything after all."*  Yes you did.  A custom class implicitly extends `Object`.  Call the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) or [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) methods to confirm it. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Shape is just that: a shape. A circle is a shape. A rectangle is a shape. But a circle with a number inside it is not a shape. My guess is that you in fact want something like this:

```
public class CircleWithNumberInside extends JComponent {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO draw a circle, and draw a number inside it.
    }
}
```

Comment: draw method from Graphics2D only accepts Shape objects; i will try to implement Shape interface

Comment: The idea is that you don't pass an object to Graphics2D so that the graphics paints the object. It's the reverse: the Graphics2D is passed to components by Swing so that they paint themselves on the Graphics2D.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly implement the [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface yourself, but there's no need when you can use an  existing subclass, such as [`Ellipse2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html). Just construct it with the same value for `width` and `height`. There's an example [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/scaledview) that shows how to center an arbitrary glyph in an `Ellipse2D.Double`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the class Shape, which inside you would have to override the paintComponent so that the Graphics2D object knows what to draw.

Comment: Shape is an interface, and it has a lot of abstract methods that i don't need

Comment: The Shape interface has no paintComponent method to override, and this makes sense as this is a method of JComponent and its children, not Shape. Instead Shape has code that allows a Graphics2D object draw it or fill it.